# Flex use constants Container

Tags: flex-lexer

i have to program a compiler with flex.

But i don't like the given code and want to make my self.

lexfile.l:

```
{%
    typedef enum { EQ=0, NE, PLUS, MINUS, SEMICOLON } punctuationType;
    typedef enum { PRINT=100, WHILE, IDENT } keywordType;
%}

%%
    "!="                            {   return NEQ; }
    "="                             {   return EQ; }
    "+"                             {   return PLUS; }
    "-"                             {   return MINUS; }
    ";"                             {   return SEMICOLON; }

%%
```

Is there a better solution?

I have searched for a solution but the other solution is to define the Constants.

```
#define EQ 0
#define NE 1
...
```

Output Example:

```
 Operator  EQ
 Operator  NE
```

The Question is only, if there is a better type instead the Enum

Comment: Are you using this in conjunction with bison?  If so, you typically define the tokens in bison itself.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you return has to be understood by the compiler. If you're using `yacc,` you don't get the choice: you have to abide by whatever `%token` generates, which are defined for you in `y.tab.h.:` you don't have to do anything at all.

On the other hand there's no need to have either names or `flex` rules for the single-char special characters: you can just return `yytext[0]` for all of them and use the corresponding literals in the `.y` file.

You don't really give enough details for further comment.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. There is no code here that would produce that output, and you haven't clarified anything else.

Comment: sorry i was in rush last time ;)  I wanted a output at the first time to look, if the regex understand everything right. :)   Now i have created an abstract class lexType and punctuationType and the other class extends from lexType.